# How to compute $|\{z \in \mathbb{Z} \mid z > -10, z^3 <0 \}|$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Compute $|\{z \in \mathbb{Z} \mid z > -10, z^3 <0 \}|$.

How do you compute these type of problems?

I know it says $z$ of all integers, $z$ has to be greater than $-10$ though by $z^3$ is less than 0.

I feel like that's a range, but not sure how you supposed to compute it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

This notation means that an element of this set is an integer $z$ such that $z > -10$ and $z^3 <0.$ For instance, $-1$ is in the set. Because $-1$ is an integer, $-1 > -10$ and $(-1)^3=-1 < 0.$ Can you find the rest?

Comment: ah ok, so it'd be -1 through -9 since they're all negative integers

Comment: Yes, the condition $z^3<0$ is equivalent to $z<0.$ That is the answer. (Well, that's the set... the answer to the actual question is 9.)